# How to print a div as page header in html

Tags: html

How can I write a stylesheet to make a particular div element be repeated at the top of every page of a print out?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">

    thead { display:table-header-group }
    tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>heading</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr><td>notes</td></tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- 500 more rows -->
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

thank you

Comment: I really can't figure out what you're trying to ask. "i was wondering if there is any way to print a div in all of printing html pages" is not a sentence in English.

Comment: Are you trying to make Office Word like page headers? If so, I think you are out of luck without some trickery with JavaScript.

Comment: No, you simply can't with CSS!

Comment: @Ben Lee: sry i mean a html page which prints a div as its header in each page for print

Comment: I know at least IE will repeat the header of a table if the table stretches more than one page, So you could wrap the entire page inside a table. Not real pretty, and might cause other problems.

Answer (score 0):

"i was wondering if there is any way to print a div in all of printing html pages". As I understand you need to google for master pages. If you want header for multiple pages you should use PHP to deliver it.

Comment: i can not install web services . im writing a win app and i used html to generate dynamic reports .